# How do I troubleshoot an 80 column card on an Apple //e?

Tags: apple-ii, text

I have a IIe (boots as enhanced: Apple //e), motherboard 607-0187-A, and 80 column text card 607-0103-J.
They came together and I think they're compatible, but not sure.

When I boot to DOS 3.3 then type `PR#3` (capslock is on) to activate, the system restarts.

When I boot to ProDOS 1.1.1 then type `PR#3` I get "NO DEVICE CONNECTED".

When I boot with no disk then type `PR#3` the system hangs.

I've followed the "*80-Column Text Card Manual For //e Only*" and it looks like I'm doing things right.  But I'm certainly not getting the results anticipated.

Do you have some tips to share?

Comment: Is the 80 column card inserted in slot 3?

Comment: "NO DEVICE CONNECTED" means what ProDOS reads from the card ROM doesn't match what it expects to find. So it's some kind of hardware problem: bad contact, or something broken on the card.

Comment: This is more of a forum-style trouble-shooting question. Is it in the AUX slot? (Not slot 3.) Oriented correctly? If so then yeah, possibly a hardware problem. Typically the first step is to remove all other cards and swap the 80 column card (into another //e, and another card into this one).

Comment: It's in the Aux slot oriented correctly, and I've tried it in two //e, with the only other hardware being a drive card. Same results. I'll chalk it up to a bad card. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot the easiest thing to try - the Apple's built-in self test with Ctrl-Closed-Apple-Reset. That tests AUX RAM. Another thing to check for is if there's a jumper on the card is should be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip @NickWestgate: RAM ZP 00000100 (3rd ram in main memory faulty). Also, jumper is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comments were helpful I've collated them into an answer.

Things to check:

- Is the card in the AUX slot? Not slot 3 - that's usually where II or II+ 80-column cards go.
- Is the card oriented correctly? E.g. one end might have "Keyboard" printed on it.
- If there's a jumper on the card it should be closed

Things to try:

- Remove all other cards.
- Swap the suspect 80 column card into another (known working) //e.
- Swap another (known working) 80 column card into the suspect //e.
- Try Apple's built-in self test by pressing Ctrl-Closed-Apple-Reset. That tests AUX RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Say, didn't you have almost much of [the same issue with another I/O card](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/how-to-test-an-orange-micro-grappler-card) just recently?

Chances are good that the IOU chip is dead. It's prone to die in quite creative ways. Get a new one and try a swap (or just another IIe anyway).

Comment: This is an old question that I just today edited and answered. Please read the comments on the question.